# How to specify boundary behavior for SciPy's interp1d

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to set the behavior at the boundaries for SciPy's `interp1d` function, which [according to the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) should be possible:

```
Behavior at the boundary can be specified at instantiation time.
```

But I have not found any further information on this.
*The [interp1d documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) does not mention it all.*

**So: How can I define the behavior?**

*Side-curiosity: What is the default boundary behavior it uses?*

---

---

**Edit:** Examples (Assuming data points between `x=0` and `x=n` and cubic interpolation)

I know of at least three types of boundary behavior that I would like to be able to specify:

*flat:* I could demand the function to flat out, in other words derivations to be zero.

```
f'(0)  = f'(n)  = 0
f''(0) = f''(n) = 0
```

---

*cyclic:* Something among the lines of

```
f'(0)  = f'(n)
f''(0) = f''(n)
```

Thus the beginning and end have same "slope".

---

*manual:* Or I could manually provide the values for the derivatives...

```
f'(0)  = ...
f'(n)  = ...
f''(0) = ...
f''(n) = ...
```

Although probably not for all four of them at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that sentence in the documentation is badly phrased, just ignore it.

The `interp1d` function, at present, does not allow to specify the boundary behaviour,

- For linear interpolation, we simply don't have a choice about it.
- For higher order interpolation `interp1d` uses the spline constructor `scipy.interpolate.splmake` with the default parameter `kind='smoothest'`, so again no choice on the boundary behaviour there.

On the other hand, you might want to have a look at `scipy.interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial`  which represents the curve with piecewise polynomials and has the ability to specify the derivatives (although for all knots and not only at the boundaries).

Comment: According to my limited understanding, the "slope" (i.e. derivations) are not directly related to the order: Assuming data points between `x=0` and `x=n` and cubic interpolation, I could demand the function to flat out, in other words derivations to be zero (i.e. `f'(0)=f'(n)=0` and `f''(0)=f''(n)=0`). Or I could ask for something among the lines of `f'(0)=f'(n)` and `f''(0)=f''(n)` (beginning and end have same "slope"). Or I could manually provide the values for the derivatives...

Comment: @neopostmodern True. I updated the post above to take into account the edits in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I kind find anything on `scipy.interpolate.splmake` (except people complaining that the documentation went missing). I'll accept your answer since it's apparently **just not possible** in *SciPy* (what I asked for) and I'll post my workaround/own implementation later.

Comment: Thanks. Well, maybe `splmake` wasn't intended too much to be exposed to the users, hence the missing documentation. The source  can be found at  https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py#L2116

Comment: I suppose "later" means "never".